# Set COD on Android bluetooth server

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing a bluetooth server over Android. The client I want to be connected has established a COD (Class of Device) filter, in order I don't catch the connection unless I have a concrete COD.

Are there any way for establishing the COD of the Bluetooth adapter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have stopped looking here, but I'll try my luck anyway. you may be able to alter the CoD of the device using hcitool through adb shell. try entering in the following

hciconfig hci0 class 0x002504

With whatever class you want.

You can also try changing the CoD in /system/etc/bluetooth/main.conf.

I am searching for a solution to this problem myself and unfortunately because of the way Samsung implemented the bluetooth stack on the Galaxy S neither work. If anyone else has any other solutions please respond to my XDA post [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=901780)